# How to run MPI compatible applications from Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, process, mpi, jupyter-notebook, execution

So I have a trobule with `gmsh`.

Direct execution works fine:

```
!gmsh -3 -algo meshadapt tmp_0.geo -o SFM.msh
```

While execution from code fails:

```
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(
            ["gmsh", "gmsh -3 -algo meshadapt tmp_0.geo -o SFM.msh"],
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
            ).strip().decode('utf8')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    out = e.output
print(out)
```

with:

> b"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n[[23419,1],0]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module\nwas
>   unable to find any relevant network interfaces:\n\nModule: OpenFabrics
>   (openib)\n  Host: 931136e3f6fe\n\nAnother transport will be used
>   instead, although this may result in\nlower
>   performance.\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\x1b[1m\x1b[31mFatal   : Can't open display:  (FLTK internal
>   error)\x1b[0m\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\nMPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD \nwith errorcode
>   1.\n\nNOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.\nYou may or may not see output from other processes,
>   depending on\nexactly when Open MPI kills
>   them.\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"

So how to emulate `!` execution in jupyter from Python 3 code?

---

@Hristo:

> _=/opt/conda/bin/jupyter SHLVL=1 PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>   HOSTNAME=931136e3f6fe HOME=/root LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 PWD=/ JPY_PARENT_PID=1
>   LANG=C.UTF-8 TERM=xterm-color CLICOLOR=1 PAGER=cat GIT_PAGER=cat
>   MPLBACKEND=module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline env DISPLAY=:0 gmsh
>   -3 -algo meshadapt tmp_0.geo -o SFM.msh

@Gilles:
Same result.

Comment: Can you `export OMPI_MCA_btl=^openib` and try again ? It is hard to figure out whether the root cause is infiniband (MPI) or the display issue (likely related to the app)

Comment: It's complaining that it cannot open a connection to the display server, which means the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set properly. Try running the command as `["env", "env DISPLAY=:0 gmsh -3 -algo ..."]`. Do an `echo $DISPLAY` in a graphical terminal to obtain the proper value. If the Jupyter server is running on under a different account, it will likely not work unless `xhost +` is issued in a terminal (dangerous - disables display server authentication). It will likely not work at all if Jupyter is running on a different host.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the root cause is the `$DISPLAY` environment variable is not set.

first make sure `$DISPLAY` is set when your Jupyter notebook starts.
you might also have to direct `mpirun` to export it to all the MPI tasks.

starting from Open MPI 3.0.0, you can achieve this with

`export OMPI_MCA_mca_base_env_list=DISPLAY`

before starting your Jupyter notebook

By the way, should your application need to open the X display ?
If it does not do any graphics, then it could be adjusted to work correctly when no display is available.

**[ADDENDUM]**

An other possibility is that `gmsh` thinks a display is available since `DISPLAY` is set, so it tries to open it and fails. You can try to unset this environment variable, and see how things go, both from the command line (e.g. *interactive* mode) and via the notebook (e.g. *batch* mode)